# Storyboard Utility App

Tags: ios, authentication

I have a storyboard Utility app that needs to be logged in before it shows any content. How would I make the login form appear until the app is logged in successfully.

Answer (score 1):

A Utility app starts with a 'Main View Controller' with a modal segue to a 'Flipside View Controller'.  In your app it sounds like you need the following:

- The 'Main View Controller' is a placeholder, that shows nothing
- The 'Main View Controller' has two segues, one to your content and one to a login form
- When your app starts the storyboard begins at the (empty) 'Main view Controler'
- Your app immediately segues, programmatically, to either your content or the login